# is it possible to replace index number to string in String.Format in C#?

Tags: c#, string

Can I use `string.Format` like this?

**1 ) Replace Number to String**

```
string sample = "Hello, {name}";

//I want to put a name string into {name}, is it possible?
```

****2 ) Is it possible add strings one by one to string template**

```
string sample = "My name is {0}, I am living in {1} ...";

// put {0} value
// and put {1} value separately

ex)
sample[0] = "MIKE";
sample[1] = "Los Anageles";
```

Comment: If you imagine that after the assignment `sample[0] = "MIKE";`, there's a string somewhere with the value `"My name is MIKE, I am living in {1} ...";`, then there's no built-in way to do this.  You could create a class to achieve this, but unless you have a compelling use case for it, I doubt it would be worth the effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1:**

```
string sample1 = "Hello, {name}";
Console.WriteLine(sample1.Replace("{name}", "John Smith"));
```

**2:**

```
string sample2 = "My name is {0}, I am living in {1} ..."; 
var parms = new ArrayList();
parms.Add("John");
parms.Add("LA");
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(sample2, parms.ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 3):

1. No
2. Yes; just build an array, then pass that array to `String.Format` ([this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d.aspx) is the particular overload you would be using):

   ```
   object[] values = new object[2];
   values[0] = ...;
   values[1] = ...;
   String.Format(someString, values);
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you accomplish #2:

```
    [Test]
    public void Passing_StringArray_Into_StringFormat()
    {
        var replacements = new string[]
            {
                "MIKE",
                "Los Angeles"
            };
        string sample = string.Format("My name is {0}, I am living in {1} ...", replacements);

        Assert.AreEqual("My name is MIKE, I am living in Los Angeles ...", sample);
    }
```

Comment: As a comment on my own code snippet there; you could actually use `object[]` instead of `string[]`.  I just used a `string[]` because your example just had strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use James Newton-King's FormatWith: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2008/03/29/formatwith-2-0-string-formatting-with-named-variables.aspx

Phil Haack has a good post about it: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/01/04/fun-with-named-formats-string-parsing-and-edge-cases.aspx